# Fast shutter to take image of photons

Tags: optics, electric-circuits, photons

Let's guess there is a very sensitive photographic film so we can capture an image of each photon as a small black dot.

Looking at photo of green light I can see $~2500$ photons per square meter. The light intensity is about $10^{-6}$ Watt per sq.m. I can't understand how the fast shutter works. It is so fast that the time exposure is $~10^{-9}$ sec. Is that an electronic shutter and how it works so fast?
Any explanation about possible principals are highly welcomed.

Comment: Your film isn't $1\ m^2$ in size, is it?

Comment: @ The Photon Right, the size of the photo is about 0.1x0.1meter.

Comment: Are you asking about some actual camera? Some actual film that you have seen? A [Kerr Cell Shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_cell_shutter), which has no moving parts, can "open" and "close" in just a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov and there were no optics between the film and where you measured 1 uW/m^2?

Comment: Absorbimg a photon is not the same as imaging it. I wouldn't know how to define the _image_ of a photon.

Comment: @ The Photon I saw a few films  and it is stated that the exposure time is 1ns. Unfortunately I did not have the camera on hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified a camera, just a photograph showing a lot of dots.  If each dot is indeed a photon detection, no fast shutter is needed.  All that's needed is dim enough light that roughly 2500 photons per square meter hit the photodetector within the actual shutter time -- which can be seconds or minutes long.